# Avoid dynamic table rows with different number of rows to flow to different pages in an XWPFDocument(Apache POI)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a code to create a word document on the fly using Apache POI API.
The document is expected to have some tables with varying number of rows(number of columns are fixed).
Currently I have placed each table onto different pages.
I need to know or is there any way to start placing tables one below another, if a page break is found, shift that table on next page and then subsequent table continues below?
I tried the below(where document is XWPFDocument), but it didn't worked

```
XWPFTable table1 = document.createTable();
XWPFTableRow tableRow1 = table1.createRow();
tableRow1.setCantSplitRow(true);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822029/apache-poi-3-13-offline-offset-elements-for-a-doc/34825848#34825848

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [XWPFTableRow.setCantSplitRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableRow.html#setCantSplitRow-boolean-) does only control whether the table row itself may be divided by a page break.

But what you wants is [Keep text together](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d). So we need to use `CTPPrBase.addNewKeepNext`. If this is set `ON` or `true`, then this paragraph should not be divided from the next paragraph. Also we schould set `CTPPrBase.addNewKeepLines` to `ON` or `true`. This means: Don't split the paragraph itself.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

//import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff; // up to Apache POI 4

import java.util.Random;

public class CreateWordTableKeepTogether {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  int numtables = 5;
  int numrows;
  Random random = new Random();
  int numcols = 5;

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The tables:");

  for (int t = 0; t < numtables; t++) {

   numrows = random.nextInt(10) + 3;

   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("Table " + (t+1));

   //don't split the paragraph itself
   //paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewKeepLines().setVal(STOnOff.ON); // up to Apache POI 4
   paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewKeepLines().setVal(true); // since Apache POI 5
   //keep this paragraph together with the next paragraph
   //paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewKeepNext().setVal(STOnOff.ON); // up to Apache POI 4
   paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewKeepNext().setVal(true); // since Apache POI 5

   XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

   for (int r = 0; r < numrows; r++) {
    XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(r);
    if (row == null) row = table.createRow();

    //don't divide this row
    row.setCantSplitRow(true);

    for (int c = 0; c < numcols; c++) {
     XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(c);
     if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell();
     paragraph = cell.getParagraphArray(0);
     if (paragraph == null) paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
     run = paragraph.createRun();
     run.setText("T" + (t+1) + "R" + (r+1) + "C" + (c+1));

     if (c == 0) { //only necessary for column one, since further columns in this row are protected by setCantSplitRow
      //paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewKeepLines().setVal(STOnOff.ON); // up to Apache POI 4
      //paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewKeepNext().setVal(STOnOff.ON); // up to Apache POI 4
      paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewKeepLines().setVal(true); // since Apache POI 5
      paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewKeepNext().setVal(true); // since Apache POI 5
     }

    }  
   }

   //this is necessary, since it is the only paragraph which allows page breaks
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  }
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordTableKeepTogether.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did got the above solution from the link u shared previously. Was a gr8 help. :)