# How to keep track of inserted page numbers or get a row reference when a page number is changing in .docx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I am creating a Java application in which I am interacting with document file .docx. I am using Apache POI to generate it and modify into it.
The existing file is having tables like:
[Tables that are created initially.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCfvv.png)

I have to add the rows in the first table so that the output is something like: [The way the 2 tables should be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OTUV.png)

So this is like I am allowing table 1 to occupy the space till it can go in document page, it is followed by another table. This type of table is needed because after that I am removing its inside borders and it shows something like: [how it should be shown with inside borders removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySKoG.png).

I am adding the blank rows using this piece of code..

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    oldRow = table.getRow(i);
    newRow = table.insertNewTableRow(i + 1);
    for (int j = 0; j < oldRow.getTableCells().size(); j++) {
        cell = newRow.createCell();
        CTTcPr ctTcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
        ctTcPr.addNewTcBorders().addNewTop().setVal(STBorder.NIL);                        
        ctTcPr.addNewTcBorders().addNewBottom().setVal(STBorder.NIL);
        CTTblWidth cellWidth = ctTcPr.addNewTcW(); 
        cellWidth.setType(oldRow.getCell(j).getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcW().getType());

        // sets type of width
        BigInteger width = oldRow.getCell(j).getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcW().getW();
        cellWidth.setW(width);  // sets width

        if (oldRow.getCell(j).getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan() != null) {                          
           ctTcPr.setGridSpan(oldRow.getCell(j). 
           getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan()); // sets grid span if any
        }
    }
}
```

In few of the lines in starting, I am adding value as something like:

```
        paragraph = row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0);
        if (paragraph == null) {
            paragraph = row.getCell(0).addParagraph();
        }
        run = setRunAndParagraph(paragraph);
        run.setText(itemNames[i]);
```

All this works nicely, this code was helped by a great coder here who helped me to solve earlier issue.

Now, when I am inserting the rows, I can manually count that for A4 size page, this many rows will be there in table 1, and can iterate likewise. But, the issue is, some item names are wider than column length and as word wrap is on, row for that particular item takes height twice as normal. So, I can get number of rows but not exactly decide how many lines occupied by the items.

The rows appended are for better look and application specific so I thought of an approach that may work:
I am adding page numbers in footer, after inserting a blank row, I am checking whether total page numbers of a document changed or not, if yes that means the code stops there. And as there's 1 excess row I am removing it.

But the issue here arise is I am not able to get page number. I tried
`document.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages();`

But that always shows 1 even if total pages becomes 2. I searched for an approach stating to check form-feed but I think I am having tables here so I don't know it will be helpful approach or not. So I went for adding page number in the page as a field but that also gave 1 every time. Then I tried to do it with footer and this is how I am writing the page number.

```
            XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy p = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();
        XWPFFooter f = p.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

        paragraph = f.createParagraph();
        //paragraph.createRun().setText("Page: ");
        paragraph.createRun();
        paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* MERGEFORMAT");
```

Now I don't know how to get value of this field, I tried getText() on footer but it did not gave the number. I read that fields are related to paragraph so I tried to get the paragraph from the footer and tried to call getText() but the output is nothing. So can someone help me with this scenario? Right now I am getting the response like this: [some part of second table going in next page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuW1p.png)

I tried to implement solution I found, but I could not get it resolved yet. so if someone can help me in this scenario like how to fetch this page numbers from the field inserted in the document, it would be really great. I tried to provide more details so that if there's a better approach than this then also someone can suggest the same. Thank you.. :)

Comment: If I understood your big amount of prosa right, then table 2 shall be a footer table in the page. So I would putting it in the page footer then. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572996/how-to-add-a-table-to-header-or-footer/39578388#39578388 I have shown how to put a table in the header. This also is possible in the footer.

Comment: Hello sir, last time also you had solved my query and today also you commented on this. Thank you so much for that.. I saw that answer and that's really great. I can move the table in footer, but then also the issue of filling the empty region will be similar. I mean I can insert blank rows to fill the region but how to get how many rows should be there so that it won't exceed the page. Because for some item names bigger than column width, it requires 2 lines and for rest it needs 1 line. So how to insert blank rows so that they are inserted till it reaches footer?

Comment: Then it seems I have not understood your description right. Now it sounds as if you wants keeping together the rows of table 2 always on one page. This is possible in word using [Keep text together](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d). I have answerd this already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822029/apache-poi-3-13-offline-offset-elements-for-a-doc/34825848#34825848. This answer may be outdated. So try it and report problems with it either here or there.

Comment: no no sir, you had understood it right. the second table is to be kept at the end of page that's correct. Its size is fixed so let's say I set it as a footer. Now, for table 1 let's say the document allows 35 rows in total. I am filling the data of 10 items, among which 3 has bigger names so their rows occupy twice the height of normal row. So they took 7 + 6 = 13 rows instead of 10. So I want to keep track of the rows inserted in next page, so that I can remove them.

Comment: As they will be blank rows, removing them won't be an issue as they are for presentation purpose. So is there a way to achieve this thing by some approach?

Comment: OK, then table 2 should definitely be in the footer. So this table is out of the normal document flow and we can forget it in further considerations But for table 1 your aproach will not be possible. Determining the exact position of the end of the page in the continous flow of paragraphs in document is not possible without rendering the pages. And `apache poi` does **not** rendering the pages. So if you wants table 1 to be the only content of page 1, then the only way is keeping the following content all together, so it must be on page 2 then.

Comment: yes sir absolutely that's where I wanted some work around for. I thought of inserting a row to the table, then saving .docx file and again opening it so I can go line by line and when the page number is increased I can get that last row was exceeded. However, this is not the feasible approach as after writing 1 line save the document then again open it and add the row likewise.. so sir is there any other way that I should follow to achieve this thing? If somehow page numbers were displayed correctly then also it might help but I either got 1 or no output.

Comment: No, even if you would saving the file and reopening using `apache poi` the automatic page break positions would not be determinable better since `apache poi` will not rendering the pages. The only way is setting the page break explicitly using [XWPFParagraph.setPageBreak](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#setPageBreak-boolean-). Or using [Keep text together](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d).

Comment: Hello sir, sorry for the late reply but I found the approach I was asking about the page break may not be working. As you said to use explicitly using page break, I wanted to keep it in 1 page so I modified the things. As you said, I put the table in footer and then I re-arranged the column widths so that every item name fits in 1 row. So I counted the number of rows that can fit in a page after adding table 2, inserted the item rows and generated empty rows using the code you had suggested in last answer. This is how I approached for the solution. Thank you sir for the great help.. :)