# Is there a way to keep track of the current page number within a XWPFDocument (Apache POI)?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

my question is similar to this one: [How to keep track of inserted page numbers or get a row reference when a page number is changing in .docx file using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374436/how-to-keep-track-of-inserted-page-numbers-or-get-a-row-reference-when-a-page-nu)

My problem: I need to add rows until the end of the current page, even when there is no more data to add.

E.g: I only have 20 entries in a dataset but I need to add more rows until i reach exactly the end of the current page and no further to prevent an unnecessary new page.

My idea was to add rows until the page number changes. But in the link above someone said that the current page number is not tracked by apache poi? is this true? If yes, does someone else has an idea how to handle this problem? Counting the rows that fit in an A4 page is not feasible, because some texts can be longer and therefore it ist not possible to tell how tall the height of a row is and how many rows there will be eventually. Thanks!

Comment: No, that is not possible as word processing does not work that way. Word processing documents are streams of text-body elements that flow across the pages. Without rendering the document there is no way to determine which body element is on which page. But all those questions seems to be [XY Problems](https://xyproblem.info/). **Why** do you think you  need to add rows until the end of the current page, even when there is no more data to add? What is the really problem you thik to solve with that?

Comment: thanks @Axel Richter, I needed to do it because it was a requirement defined by the product team. I found no other solution than fixing the height of the rows and counting the maximum amount that would fit on a page. Not beautiful but does the job